# To avoid the problem of perfect multicollinearity in binary variables, why is it fine to create separate variables for them in the linear regression?

Tags: multiple-regression, multicollinearity

I am reading Wooldridge's econometrics textbook. He provides the following example: Suppose we have a regression model relating wages to gender and education level.

wage = b0 + d0 female + b1educ + u

For the gender variable, we can create a binary variable in which female = 0 and male = 1. The textbook stated that we should not create 2 dummy variables to avoid the dummy variable trap (perfect multicollinearity).

At the same time, Wooldridge said that it is fine to do this: wage = b0male + a0female + b1educ + u. Why is it fine to include 2 dummy variables for each group? Would that not also result in perfect multicollinearity?

Comment: You don’t create separate variables (columns). You create separate values within a single column (0/1 values indicating gender).

Comment: I already know that. Wooldridge later mentioned in his book that you can create separate variables for gender to avoid the dummy variable trap.

wage = b0 + d0 female + b1educ + u

Wooldridge said that it is fine to do this:

wage = b0male + a0female + b1educ + u

Comment: You may have spotted "Some researchers prefer to drop the overall intercept in the model and to include dummy variables for each group. The equation would then be $wage = \beta_0 male + \alpha_0 female + \beta_1 educ + u$, where the intercept for men is $\beta_0$ and the intercept for women is $\alpha_0$. There is no dummy variable trap in this case because we do not have an overall intercept."  In effect you use the original $\beta_0$ as the intercept for males and the new $\alpha_0 = \beta_0+\delta_0$ as the intercept for females

Comment: Wooldridge continues "However, this formulation has little to offer, since testing for a difference in the intercepts is more difficult, and there is no generally agreed upon way to compute $R$-squared in regressions without an intercept. Therefore, we will always include an overall intercept for the base group." It also fails when you have two sets of dummy variables as you cannot lose the intercept twice.

Comment: After you expanded & clarified your question, I think the duplicate offers a complete answer. The core issue is that 
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$ is rank deficient, but $$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 \\
1 & 0  \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$ and $$
\begin{bmatrix}
 1 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$ are not. Each matrix corresponds to one of the three proposed design matrices in the question & comments. Apparently, Wooldridge's book has more discussion.